# TypeError: Cannot read property '$getIndex' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some help on how to get free of this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$getIndex' of undefined
  at Scope.<anonymous> (angularfire.min.js:1)
  at Parser.filter.fnInvoke (angular.js:10101)
  at OPERATORS.| (angular.js:9616)
  at Parser.binaryFn.extend.constant (angular.js:10046)
  at OPERATORS.| (angular.js:9616)
  at Parser.binaryFn.extend.constant (angular.js:10046)
  at OPERATORS.| (angular.js:9616)
  at Parser.binaryFn.extend.constant (angular.js:10046)
  at Object.$watchCollectionWatch (angular.js:11726)
  at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:11890)
```

Comment: Please be more specific, share your code and describe your problem correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for your data to be loaded. Something like this

```
$scope.data.$on('loaded', function() {
  console.log($scope.data.$getIndex());
});
```

Wait for `loaded` event and then try to use the `$getIndex()`